# Decent way to add a validator for DRF Field class child

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a custom DRF field element that looks like this:

```
class TimestampField(serializers.DateTimeField):
     
     def __init__(self, allow_future=True, *args, **kwargs):
         self.allow_future = allow_future

     def some_sort_of_validator(...): # Don't know how to do that
         if not self.allow_future:
              if value > timezone.now():
                  raise ValidationError('...')
```

Basically, I want to do some custom validation for that field elements. For example, I want to assure that future dates are prohibited. Looks like I need to add something that is refered to as `validator` in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#validators). And I wonder how to do that correctly, so that not to kill native validators. I found nothing regarding this neither in the DRF doc, nor in SO.

Comment: Where is the "child" in your example?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article in the docs about writing validators and a section about [writing custom validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators).

in your case, something like this should work

```py
class TimestampValidator:
    def __init__(self, allow_future):
        self.allow_future  = allow_future 

     def __call__(self, value):
        if not self.allow_future:
              if value > timestamp.now():
                  raise ValidationError('...')
```

and to use it in your actual serializer

```py
class MySerializer((serializers.Serializer):
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(validators=[TimestampValidator(allow_future=True)])
    # .. the rest of your serializer goes here
```

you can also check the [code for the built-in validators](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/validators.py) to see how they are done